# Installing Octave on Ubuntu 16.04 with Nvidia Running

Tags: octave

I am trying to install Octave on Xenial which has an Nvidia graphics card. Octave installs but quits as soon as I try to start it from command line. Please suggest any solutions. I have octave running on a number of other machines but that run smoothly. The only difference is that they dont have nvidia on them. Its weird though.

Comment: Can you list your Octave and Nvidia version numbers? Also computer make and model. This helps us narrow google searches.

Comment: Thanks indeed for the response. I have the following things:

Octave version is 4.0.0,
Nvidia: Geforce GTX 750Ti 2048mb - gddr5  - direct x 11.2 -  128 bit - oc guru II


I shall post the make and model of my computer in a while. However, I have computers of the same make and model that do let octave to work properly.

Comment: Moreover, I have an Intel® Xeon(R) CPU W3520 @ 2.67GHz × 4 with 8 GB RAM.